# How to tell Scriptrunner to ignore "org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language"

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, annotations, confluence, jira-plugin

I'm running Adaptavist ScriptRunner in Atlassian-Confluence as a Script-Makro.
I recently found out, that IntelliJ has some neat language injections

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-language-injections.html

It works just fine in intelliJ and I can work with all the benefits of code-completion etc...

```
import org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language

@Language("CSS") String cssStyle = """
table.tablesorter thead, tr, th {
    padding-right: 2px !important;
}
"""
```

you could also use a comment-Version of this feature, but then I get problems when I interrupt the String with a variable (It won't recognize the languageInsertion after the variable):

```
Integer variable = 3
//language="CSS"
String cssStyle = """
table.tablesorter thead, tr, th {
    padding-right: """+ variable +"""px !important;
}
"""
```

That doesn't happen with the @Language annotation...

The problem is, that Scriptrunner doesn't know the annotation and throws an error:

> unable to resolve class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language @ line 10, >column 1. import org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language ^ 1 error

Any thought on how I can teach Scriptrunner where to find the dependency or maybe tell Scriptrunner to ignore this annotation? It's actually just for intelliJ... Scriptrunner does't has to do anything with that import...

Best regards,
Sebastian

Comment: Does the "comment version" work if you use $variable instead of closing the string and use addition?

Comment: @Steinar no, unfortunately not...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you put your script somewhere as plaintext for ScriptRunner. The problem is that ScriptRunner tries to compile your script in the environment of Confluence. In that environment the Language annotation does not exist as it is an IntelliJ extra class and therefore throws an error.

I doubt that this will somehow possible to achieve unless you compile it already with IntelliJ into a so called ScriptPlugin and installs the plugin itself then. This might not be that trivial, but if you want to go that path you can read more here: https://docs.adaptavist.com/sr4bib/latest/best-practices/write-code/create-a-script-plugin